# RangeSlider causes NullPointerException when pressing Tab on the focused slider

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-8, controlsfx

I'm getting NullPointerException when using [org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html). Here is the simple code example:

```
package experimental_main;

import org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Experimental_start extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Button button = new Button("Click me");
        RangeSlider rangeSlider = new RangeSlider(0, 10, 2, 4);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(rangeSlider);
        borderPane.setTop(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The exception occurs when pressing Tab while right thumb of RangeSlider is focused or pressing Shift+Tab while its left thumb is focused. These key pressings cause to lose focus from RangeSlider as expected, but this action also causes NullPointerException. Here is exception's stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TraversalEngine.select(Unknown Source)
at impl.org.controlsfx.skin.RangeSliderSkin$5.handle(RangeSliderSkin.java:150)
at impl.org.controlsfx.skin.RangeSliderSkin$5.handle(RangeSliderSkin.java:132)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There is no exception when pressing Tab (or Shift+Tab) with a view to make RangeSlider's thumb focused.

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug? Is there alternative to RangeSlider class realizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This listener of the `RangeSliderSkin` seems to cause the `NPE`:

```
 EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (KeyCode.TAB.equals(event.getCode())) {
                    if (lowThumb.isFocused()) {
                        if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                            lowThumb.setFocus(false);
                            new ParentTraversalEngine(rangeSlider).select(rangeSlider, Direction.PREVIOUS);
                        } else {
                            lowThumb.setFocus(false);
                            highThumb.setFocus(true);
                        }
                        event.consume();
                    } else if (highThumb.isFocused()) {
                        if(event.isShiftDown()) {
                            highThumb.setFocus(false);
                            lowThumb.setFocus(true);
                        } else {
                            highThumb.setFocus(false);
                            new ParentTraversalEngine(rangeSlider).select(rangeSlider, Direction.NEXT);
                        }
                        event.consume();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

To be more specific, the line `new ParentTraversalEngine(rangeSlider).select(rangeSlider, Direction.NEXT);`
`ParentTraversalEngine` is initalized without an `Algorithm` argument, so calling `select(rangeSlider, Direction.NEXT)` is causing a NPE, as it is supposed to:

> Throws:
>           java.lang.NullPointerException - if there is no algorithm

[javadoc](http://jonathangiles.net/javafx/jdk9/traversal/javafx/scene/traversal/TraversalEngine.html#select-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.traversal.TraversalDirection-)

Comment: The problem is exactly you've described. I didn't find the way to determine which of rangeSlider's thumbs is exactly focused. Making layout in fxml doesn't help too. The only way I see is to consume all Tab pressings when `RangeSlider` object is focused.  Thank you for hint.

Comment: You can get a reference to the thumbs by using the `node.lookup(selector)` :  `Node lowThumb = rangeSlider.lookup(".low-thumb");
        Node highThumb = rangeSlider.lookup(".high-thumb");`

Comment: `rangeSlider.lookup(".range-slider")` really finds Node with ".range-slider" class. But `rangeSlider.lookup(".low-thumb")` and `rangeSlider.lookup(".high-thumb")` both return `null`. All these classes and some other (which cannot be found too) exist in `"org\controlsfx\control\rangeslider.css"` which I found in `controlsfx-8.40.10.jar` file. The only distinctive feature is that `".range-slider"` in this css file is always a "high level" (every part begins with `".range-slider .some_sub_class"`). I feel like I'm going in a wrong way... (((

Comment: Try to use lookup(.low-thumb) after the stage is shown.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you very much!  Now I've just added event filter ([Node.addEventFilter(EventType<T>, EventHandler<? super T>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-)) to `RangeSlider` object, which filters `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` and consumes `TAB` or `Shift+TAB` manually moving focus to neighbour nodes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed beginning from version `8.40.13`.